# How to handle $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{0}^h f(s) ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

In my lecture notes I found the following identity: 
$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{0}^h f(s) ds = f(0)$$
without any explanation on what's going on here. I think in the lecture we said that $f$ should be a $C^1$-function but I'm not sure, whether one needs this assumption or not.
My question now is: Why does this identity hold? I was thinking of using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus - but how do I know that there is a function $F$ s.t. $F'(x) = f(x)$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Many ways to show this. One route is to use [L'Hopitals rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) + the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: If f is integrable, then the integral is F(s)-F(0). Take a look of the definition of derivative.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is clear, that the identity holds if there is a function $F$ as described above. But does such an $F$ exist?

Comment: The fundamental theorem needs f to be continuous.

Comment: The required condition is that f has to be conituous at 0 for such a function F to exist......

Comment: @Steven, Existence of an antiderivative $F$ is a part of the statement of FTC for continuous functions.

Comment: Ah yes! I checked again. Totally forgot that part. Anyway, thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to prove this limit whithout using derivatives, but only using the continuity of $f$. We want to show that
$$\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h f(s) ds-f(0)\right|<\epsilon$$
when $h<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$.
Now 
$$\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h f(s) ds-f(0)\right|=\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h [f(s)-f(0)] ds\right|\le \frac{1}{h}\int_0^h |f(s)-f(0)| ds.$$
I used the fact that $\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h f(0)ds=f(0)$.
Since $f$ is continuous, for every $\epsilon$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ when $|x-y|<\delta$. Now if we take $h<\delta$, then $|f(s)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ when $s \in (0,h)$, hence
$$\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h |f(s)-f(0)| ds\le \frac{1}{h}\int_0^h \epsilon ds=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Very nice, thank you for your answer!